# Using Java supplier/Function to pass method in static method

Tags: java, java-8, supplier

I have a couple of classes:

```
public class TextContent {
    private String externalId;
}

public class ImageContent {
    private String externalImageId;
}

public static void validateImageInput(List<ImageContent> imageAssets, String requestId) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(imageAssets)) {
        throw some Error;
    }

    Set<String> uniqueIds = imageAssets.stream().map(ImageContent::externalImageId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(uniqueIds.size() != imageAssets().size()) {
        throw some Error;
    }

    //Do some processing
}

public static void validateTextInput(List<TextContent> textAssets, String requestId) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(textAssets)) {
        throw some Error;
    }

    Set<String> uniqueIds = textAssets.stream().map(ImageContent::externalId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(uniqueIds.size() != textAssets().size()) {
        throw some Error;
    }

    //Do some processing
}
```

As you can see the validation part is the same for both these classes. And I wanted to try and make this a common method. For that:

```
public static void validateInput(List<?> assets, String requestId, Supplier<String> mapper) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(assets)) {
        throw some error;
    }

    Set<String> uniqueIds = assets.stream().map(x -> mapper.get()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(uniqueIds.size() != assets().size()) {
        throw some Error;
    }
}
```

and then call it with :

```
public static void validateAllInputs(List<ImageContent> imageAssets, List<TextContent> textAssets, String requestId) {
    validateInput(imageAssets, requestId, ImageContent::externalImageId);
    validateInput(textAssets, requestId, TextContent::externalId);
    doSomeProcessingWithText(textAssets, requestId);
    doSomeProcessingWithImage(imageAssets, requestId);
}
```

But I get an error saying `Non static method cannot be referenced from static context.`

Edit:
The other option I tried was using `Function` , i.e I pass in a `<TextContent, String> mapper` and in my stream I use `.map(x -> mapper.apply(x)`. However when I try passing it to the function `validateInputs(textAsset, requestId, TextContent::externalId)` I get the same error `Non static method cannot be referenced from static context.`

Comment: From where are you calling this method?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala From a static method

Comment: Could you please post that code too?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done this with the help of generics:

```
public static <T> void validateInput(List<T> assets, String requestId, Function<T, String> mapper) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(assets)) {
        throw some error;
    }

    Set<String> uniqueIds = assets.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(uniqueIds.size() != assets().size()) {
        throw some Error;
    }
}
```

And then call it using:

```
validateInput(imageAssets, requestId, ImageContent::externalImageId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making both types implement the same interface:

```
public interface Content {
    public String getExternalId();

    public static String externalId(Content content) {
        return content == null ? null : content.getExternalId();
    }
}
```

Then change the `validateInput` signature to:

```
public static void validateInput(List<? extends Content> assets, String requestId) {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(assets)) {
        throw some error;
    }

    Set<String> uniqueIds = assets.stream().map(Content::externalId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    if(uniqueIds.size() != assets.size()) {
        throw some error;
    }

    //Do some processing
}
```

And if you still want to extract a common method here, you can write one like this:

```
public static <E> void commonValidate(List<E> assets, String requestId, Function<E, String> mapper) {
    Set<String> uniqueIds = assets.stream().map(mapper).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```